# Write a list directly to gcs file

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, stream, google-cloud-storage

Currently i have a simple python code which writes elements of a list to file. How can i do the same, but write to file in Google cloud storage

Current code :

```
with open('/home/nitin/temp.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in ["Nitin", "Agarwal"]:
        f.write(item[0]+'\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

I tend to find blob's "upload_from_string" method preferable when dumping some in-memory data to GSC, instead of dumping to a local file and uploading it to GSC.

Would this work for you?

```
from google.cloud.storage import Blob

data = ["Nitin", "Agarwal"]
client = storage.Client(project="my-project")
bucket = client.get_bucket("my-bucket")
blob = Blob("data", bucket)
blob.upload_from_string("\n".join(data))
```

https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_string

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Storage (GCS) is also known as blob storage as opposed to file storage.  Don't think of GCS as holding files, think of it as holding blobs of data.  This means that you can't use file system APIs.  Instead, think of building the blob of data that you want to write into GCS locally and then writing that complete blob into GCS as a unit.  When you write data into GCS, it is immutable ... this means that once written, you can't change it (you can delete it and rewrite a new copy).  This means that you can't append to a blob.

Here is a good example:

[Using Cloud Storage with Python](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-storage)